# The Ionic 2 template project gives me syntax errors for @Page decorator and constructor ()

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have created an Ionic 2 beta app and when I open it in Visual Studio (VS) 2015 I get syntax errors inside all of the .js files for the `@Page` decorator and the `contructor () { }`. Being new to Ionic 2 I'm unsure if the error is related to TypeScript, Ionic, Angular, or VS just being a pain.

Here's an example screenshot of the tabs.js file...

[image]

Could anybody explain why I get these syntax errors and what I can do to resolve them?

Comment: Do you have a tsconfig.json file?

Comment: Just confirming - you're seeing these errors inside of a `.js` file, instead of a `.ts` file, correct?

Comment: The app doesn't have a tsconfig.json file and yes all of the errors are inside .js files. None of the default files are of type .ts. I used the following command to create the app `ionic start test-app --v2` which creates Ionic's default tabs style template

Comment: I've realised I can create Ionic 2 apps with a TypeScript template by using the following command `ionic start test-app --v2 --ts` and this method provides me with .ts files and a tsconfig.json so I no longer get the errors. I think this is now resolved thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer has been updated with (hopefully) a better explanation**

After some online reading I've realised this is not a code breaking problem but more of an inconvenience as a developer seeing these errors on the screen.

**Why does it happen?**

Visual Studio (and possibly other IDE's) classes certain characters as invalid for .js files. Angular 2 and Ionic 2 reserve some of these characters (such as @) for special purposes, for example using `@Page` will tell Ionic to create a new navigation component so that it can be used with `NavController`.

**Solution**

Ionic give you the choice to create an application in JavaScript or TypeScript. If you prefer to use JavaScript you will just have to put up with these visual errors because the application will still run and work as expected (as far as I'm aware).

Or

You can use TypeScript. TypeScript will accept these characters which means these errors are no more. The only downside is you will need to learn TypeScript, but this becomes a good thing IMO. To create a TypeScript project just add `--ts` at the end of the CLI command, for example `ionic start testApp --v2 --ts`

I'll leave this here in case anybody else experiences a similar problem and may find this information useful.